# Can't edit a webpage

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Every time I open DevTools in a specific webpage (not mentioned for privacy), it takes me to this code in `Sources` tab:

```
(function anonymous(
) {
debugger
})
```

- This code is shown to be written in a file that changes every reload and with name starting with **VM** (like **VM459**).
- Every time I press <kbd>F8</kbd>, the number that is beside **VM** gets incremented by 2.
- Once I close DevTools, I get redirected to the homepage of the site.
- I have no extensions added.

Comment: The page use debugger as a hack to prevent user from debugging/view its source code in devtools.

Comment: @Jecfish, But I can view the source code!